# Problem with delete instruction about createQueryBuilder, argument missing

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.3

I have a problem with doctrine. I'm training to symfony and i get an error with the method below. 
It seems createQueryBuilder is the cause. a parameter is missing, however I found many examples as mine, thus I don't understand what is missing.

```
public function deleteAdvertWithoutApplications($days)
{
    $dateparam = (new \datetime())->modify('-' . $days . 'day');

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder()
        ->delete('Advert', 'a')
        ->where('a.application is EMPTY')
        ->andWhere('a.updatedAt < :dateparam')
        ->setParameter('dateparam', $dateparam);

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    //$query->getDQL();
    return $query->execute();
}
```

This code throw this :

`Warning: Missing argument 1 for Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::createQueryBuilder(), called in ...` etc.

the vendor code seems to be the cause

in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php (line 79)

```
/**
     * @param string $alias     
     * @param string $indexBy The index for the from.        
     * @return QueryBuilder     
*/    
public function createQueryBuilder($alias, $indexBy = null)    
{        
    return $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()            
         ->select($alias)            
         ->from($this->_entityName, $alias, $indexBy);    
}
```

Do you have anidea about what is wrong ? 
I use Doctrine, 2.5.15 and symfony 3.3.18 (php 7).

Thanks by advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error this line

```
  ->where('a.application is EMPTY')
```

Use this

```
  ->where('a.application IS  NULL')
```

Comment: Thanks, but it the same result.

Comment: in this line define your bundle    ->delete('YourBundle:Advert', 'a')

Comment: thanks a lot pedram for your help it's work 
Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Pedram !!!

ok this is the new code below

```
public function deleteAdvertWithoutApplications($days)
{
    $dateparam = (new \datetime())->modify('-' . $days . 'day');

    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->delete('OCPlatformBundle:Advert', 'a')
       ->where('a.applications is EMPTY')
       ->andWhere('a.updatedAt < :dateparam')
       ->setParameter('dateparam', $dateparam);

    $query = $qb->getQuery();

    return $query->execute();
}
```